# How to convert the value of %USERNAME% to lowercase within a Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd

I'm automating some source control software functionality using a dot bat script but given that our svn repos are hosted in a *NIX box, I'm facing the eternal case problem between these two worlds.

Is there any cmd.exe function to convert the value of the Windows system variable %USERNAME% to lower case?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: See also http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch file read text file and convert all to uppercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648560/windows-batch-file-read-text-file-and-convert-all-to-uppercase)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch-file for converting file names into lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566029/batch-file-for-converting-file-names-into-lowercase)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713621/batch-converting-variable-to-uppercase/77926965#77926965) is another solution that allows upper or lower case letters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a quick google found [this](http://cwashington.netreach.net/depo/view.asp?Index=780)...

```
@echo off
goto :end_remarks
*************************************************************************************
*
*
*    authored:Sam Wofford
*    Returns lowercase of a string
*    12:13 PM 11/13/02
**************************************************************************************
:end_remarks
setlocal
set errorlevel=-1
if {%1}=={} echo NO ARG GIVEN&call :Help &goto :endit
if {%1}=={/?} call :Help &goto :endit
call :set_LCASE_array a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

:start
set input=%1
set input=%input:"=%
set totparams=0
call :COUNT_PARAMS %input%
call :MAKE_LOWERCASE %input%
set errorlevel=
echo %convertedstring%
endlocal
goto :eof
:endit
echo %errorlevel%
endlocal
goto :eof

:MAKE_LOWERCASE
:nextstring
if {%1}=={} goto :eof
set string=%1
set /a params+=1
set STRINGCONVERTED=
set pos=0
:NEXT_CHAR
set onechar=%%string^:^~%pos%,1%%
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('set onechar') do for /f %%c in ('echo %%b') do call :checkit %%c
if not defined STRINGCONVERTED goto :NEXT_CHAR
shift /1
if %params% LSS %totparams% set convertedstring=%convertedstring% &:add one space,but not at end
goto :nextstring
goto :eof

:Help
echo USAGE:%~n0 string OR %~n0 "with spaces"
echo function returns the lowercase of the string or -1 (error)
echo strings with embedded spaces needs to be in quotes Ex. "lower case"
echo in a batch NTscript "for /f %%%%A in ('lcase STRING') do set var=%%%%A"
set errorlevel=
goto :eof

:checkit
set LCFOUND=
if /i {%1}=={echo} set STRINGCONVERTED=Y&goto :eof
set char=%1
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_=" %%A in ('set LCASE_') do call :findit %%A %char%
:skipit
if defined LCFOUND (set convertedstring=%convertedstring%%ucletter%) else (set convertedstring=%convertedstring%%char%)
set /a pos+=1
goto :eof

:set_LCASE_array
:setit
if {%1}=={} goto :eof
set LCASE_%1_=%1
SHIFT /1
goto :setit

:findit
if defined LCFOUND goto :eof
set ucletter=%1
set lcchar=%2
if /i {%ucletter%}=={%lcchar%} set LCFOUND=yes
goto :eof

:COUNT_PARAMS
:COUNTPARAMS
if {%1}=={} goto :eof
set /a totparams+=1
shift /1
goto :COUNTPARAMS
```

add that as a file (lowercase.cmd) to your path and you should be able to call it as "Lowercase.cmd %Username%", you could pipe it into another command if needed.

Comment: Thank you @Mauro :) I saved your posted script as "LCase.CMD", and I adjust LINE 11 with..

    if not "%2"=="auto" setlocal

then LINE 24 and 24 with..

    if not "%2"=="auto" echo %convertedstring%
    if not "%2"=="auto" endlocal

Now, I'm using this inline into my own batch file..

    if exist "LCase.cmd" (
      set convertedstring=
      call LCase.cmd %uid% auto
      set uid=%convertedstring%
    )

Answer (score 18):

Well, I was browsing for some syntax and stumbled upon this page. I know its old but I thought I'd take a break and give the brain a little kick.

Here's something a little shorter and manageable. This just "brute forces" all uppercase letters to lowercase letters without regards to whether the actual letter exists in the string or not. Thus the functional loop runs exactly 26 times no matter the length of the string.

Hope this helps someone.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM ***** Modify as necessary for the string source. *****
set "_STRING=%*"
if not defined _STRING set "_STRING=%USERNAME%"
set _STRING
REM ***** Modify as necessary for the string source. *****

set "_UCASE=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "_LCASE=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for /l %%a in (0,1,25) do (
   call set "_FROM=%%_UCASE:~%%a,1%%
   call set "_TO=%%_LCASE:~%%a,1%%
   call set "_STRING=%%_STRING:!_FROM!=!_TO!%%
)

set _STRING
endlocal
```

Example:

```
E:\OS.ADMIN>LCASE.BAT The Quick Fox Jumps Over The Brown Fence.
```

Result:

```
_STRING=The Quick Fox Jumps Over The Brown Fence.
_STRING=the quick fox jumps over the brown fence.
```

Comment: Somehow a `z` and a `y` belong in that sentence somewhere. :) :) :)  perhaps `The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over A Lazy Dog.` :) :) :)

Answer (score 8):

When a scripting language is installed then that can be used with a `FOR` to set a variable.

```
@FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('<<some script oneliner>>') DO @set MYVARIABLE=%%s
```

Reference: [For F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Any scripting language can be used if it can convert a string to lowercase and output the result.

**An example using Perl 5 :**

```
@FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('perl -e "print lc(pop)" %USERNAME%') DO @set USERNAME=%%s
```

**An example using PowerShell :**

```
@FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('powershell -command "$env:USERNAME.ToLower()"') DO @set USERNAME=%%s
```

These days, odds are that PowerShell is already installed by default.

Answer (score 7):

download some unix utilities for DOS from http://short.stop.home.att.net/freesoft/unix.htm
and use tr.exe (translate characters)

```
echo %USERNAME% | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"
```

I also use a DOS extended cmd replacement named 4NT which has a built in command @lower

```
echo %@lower[%USERNAME%]
```

Comment: Thanks much for your comment. I've thought about that approach but that would imply having to install that tools in each user's box, I was interested in solving the problem with existing Windows tools.

Comment: Exactly. At some point, a cleaner solution is to either use the correct tool, or compile such simple program with your favorite language, and provide it with your own software, as an external dependency.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/lowercasing-string-bat-files

lower.bat

```
echo>%1
dir /b/l %1>lower.tmp
set /p result=<lower.tmp
echo %result%
```

cmd

```
lower "Mein BinnenMajuskel"
```

result

```
mein binnenmajuskel
```

CAUTION: Quick & dirty, but also insecure and dangerous variant. Because you create two files. One called like the given string and another called lower.tmp, which contains the lowered string. What happens if you execute `lower "UserName"` in a directory, where this file or directory already exists? Especially if you delete this files afterwards ...

Improved version:

```
echo>%Temp%\%1
dir /b/l %Temp%\%1>%Temp%\lower.tmp
set /p result=<%Temp%\lower.tmp
del %Temp%\%1
del %Temp%\lower.tmp
```

Comment: Can be simplified to:
echo>%username% && dir /b/l %username%>%username% && set /p USER=<%username% && del %username%

Answer (score 7):

Probably this is the fastest way to convert a string to lowercase in batch file as it uses [macro](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html) and there are no temp files (it saves the produced string in variable called `result`):

```
@echo off

set LowerCaseMacro=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (for %%# in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "result=!result:%%#=%%#!") else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set result=

set "string=SOme STrinG WiTH lowerCAse letterS and UPCase leTTErs"
%LowerCaseMacro%%string%

echo %result%
```

Answer (score 5):

In my batch file I'm doing a comparsion between %USERNAME% and a CSV file.

The program would not work if user was logged in UperCase username.

Ex: 
Login : GB2NOGU // Won't work 
Login : gb2nogu // Works

Here I could solve my problem doing a insensitive comparison.

```
if /i %USERNAME%==gb2nogu (
     // Code here
)
```

The parameter /i tells the cmd to do a insensitive case comparison, so it'll ignore the difference between lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: very useful indeed!

Answer (score 3):

```
:: UPcase.bat ==> Store in environment variable _UPcase_ the upper case of %1
:: -> Use quotes "" when the first argument has blanks or special characteres
::
:: Adapted from -> http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd039.htm
::
:: Note that the substitution method is case insensitive, which means that
:: while working for this application, it is not useful for all character
:: substitution tasks.
::
:: More concisely, one can capitalize (if you pardon the pun) on the fact
:: that in for and the substitution lower and upper case source are
:: equivalent.
@echo off

:: %~1 -> removes quotes from the first command line argument
:: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-2-variables.html
@echo off
::setlocal EnableExtensions
    :: echo %_UPcase_%
    call :ToUpcaseWithFor "%~1" _UPcase_
    :: echo %_UPcase_% _doit_1_
::endlocal & goto :EOF
goto :EOF
::
:: ======================
:ToUpcaseWithFor
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
  set var_=%~1
  for %%c in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    set var_=!var_:%%c=%%c!
  )
endlocal & set %2=%var_%& goto :EOF

:EOF
:: UPcase.bat ==> EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer /by [@It Wasn't Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8177207/it-wasnt-me?tab=profile) [here](https://superuser.com/a/1522183/969781)

---

For a predictive character set, this substring **`Set !var:A=a!`** works, and only working with **predefined substring** in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**.

For this type of task, why not get a little help with **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)**, which can make it possible to work with unconventional accents and consonants **è, È, ä, Ä, ñ, Ñ, ç, Ç etc.**

Where the **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** will generate **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code, it will be compiled and executed at run time ....

Which solves possible user inputs, in which the sequence comes with accents and the vowels/consonants are different from the conventional ones **[a-z]** and/or **[A_Z]**

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

cd /d "%~dp0" && title <nul && title ...\%~dpnx0 /// !time:~0,8! !date!

if exist "%tmp%\ToUpLower.cs" 2>nul >nul del /q /f "%tmp%\ToUpLower.cs" 
set "_where=%__appdir__%where.exe" && set "_csc=%windir%\Microsoft.NET"
>"%temp%\ToUpLower.cs"  ( 
echo= using System; namespace SUQ1522019 ^{class Program ^{static void Main(string[] args^) ^{
echo= if (args.Length==2 ^&^& args[0].ToLower(^)=="-l"^) ^{Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToLower(^)^);^} 
echo= if (args.Length==2 ^&^& args[0].ToLower(^)=="-u"^) ^{Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToUpper(^)^);^}^}^}^}
)

set "_arg=/t:exe /out:"%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "%tmp%\ToUpLower.cs" /platform:anycpu "
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('!_where! /r "!_csc!" "csc.exe"^|findstr /lic:"k\v2\." 
')do "%%~i" !_arg! /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo

for /f tokens^=* %%U in ('"%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" -u %USERNAME%')do set "_up_case=%%U"
for /f tokens^=* %%l in ('"%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" -l %USERNAME%')do set "_low_case=%%l"

echo/  Your username upcase is: !_up_case!
echo/ Your username lowcase is: !_low_case!

echo/ >nul 2>nul copy "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "." 
del /q /f "%tmp%\ToUpLower.*" >nul 2>nul && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Outputs for **`%USERNAME%`**

  ---

```bat
 Your username upcase is: USERNAME
Your username lowcase is: username
```

---

The **`ToUpLower.cs`** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code with no escaping:

---

```bat
 using System; namespace SUQ1522019 {class Program {static void Main(string[] args) {
 if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-l") {Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToLower());} 
 if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-u") {Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToUpper());}}}}
```

---

The **`ToUpLower.cs`** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code with no escaping and indented:

---

```bat
using System
namespace SUQ1522019 
{
   class Program 
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-l") 
         {
            Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToLower());
         } 

         if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-u") 
         {
            Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToUpper());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

- This **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code was **compiled/tested** on **`csc.exe`** versions:

```bat
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

---

- This is the **command line** used to **compile** the **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code:

  ---

```bat
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /t:exe /out:"%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "%tmp%\ToUpLower.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo
```

---

- **`ToUpLower.exe` usage**  UPPER to -> lower 


  ---

```bat
ToUpLower.exe -l STRING 

:: or ..

ToUpLower.exe -L STRING
```

---

- **`ToUpLower.exe` usage**  lower to -> UPPER

---

```bat
ToUpLower.exe -u string

:: or ..

ToUpLower.exe -U string
```

---

To keep **`ToUpLower.exe`**, remove **`echo/`** from **`copy`** **command**:

---

```
echo/ >nul 2>nul copy "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "."
```

This command line will copy **`ToUpLower.exe`** from **`%temp%`** to same the same folder where your bat is running.

---

Programming Guide C#:

- **[Args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments)**
- **[ToLower](https://superuser.com/a/1522183/969781)**
- **[ToUpper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8177207/it-wasnt-me?tab=profile)**

---

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>