# Windows batch file read text file and convert all to uppercase

Tags: windows, text, batch-file, uppercase

I just simply want to replace all the text in the text file convert to uppercase.

For example of abc.txt

[Before conversion]
First Name, Last Name, Full Name
Brad, Pitt, Brad Pitt

[After conversion]
FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, FULL NAME
BRAD, PITT, BRAD PITT

Is that possible??

Comment: Lookie here: http://benohead.com/batch-convert-to-uppercase/

Comment: Please DON'T! Examples like that are the cause that many people thinks that Batch language is rudimentary and crude...

Comment: @Aacini: I take your point well. +1 on your comment. Let's hope no one emulates the code cited. And ... batch language isn't rudimentary and crude? Really!? :) Umm ... yeah. It is. Sorry to speak the unwanted truth! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Batch file below do what you want, but if the file to convert is large this method is slow...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "line=!line:%%b=%%b!"
   )
   echo !line!
)
```

To use this program, place the name of the file in the first parameter. For example, if this Batch file is called TOUPPER.BAT:

```
toupper abc.txt
```

Note that this program eliminate empty lines and any exclamation mark existent in the file. These limitations may be fixed if needed, but the program becomes even slower...

Antonio

Comment: OH MY GOD! It worked!!! My file has only a few line so I don't have any problem with the performance either!!!

Comment: how does `!line:%%b=%%b!` work? Is string replacing in cmd case-insensitive?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: yes