# How to replace multiple strings in for loop using the call command - replacing % is a problem

Tags: batch-file

**Consider the following code:**

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >NUL

rem Main thread here which shows how to change each letter to UPPERCASE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713621/batch-converting-variable-to-uppercase
rem Comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34734724/8262102
rem I want to use this code to replace multiple strings but I'm having difficulty
rem with getting % replaced with double % symbols.

set "str=Change %% to double %% and replace other ^(And convert brackets^)"
echo %str% (Old variable)
call :VALIDATE str
echo %str% (New variable)
pause
goto :EOF

:VALIDATE
if not defined %~1 exit /b
for %%A in ("^%^%=^%^%^%^%" "(='('" ")=')'") do (
call set %~1=%%%~1:%%~A%%
)
goto :EOF
```

This is replacing the `(` with `'('` and the `)` with `')'`.

I cannot get `%` to be replaced with `%%`.

I've tried to escape the `%` by using both `%%` and `^%` but no luck at this point in the code `"^%^%=^%^%^%^%"`.

I'm out of ideas as to how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you at all?

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "str=Change %% to %%%%, and %%%% to %%%%%%%%, (and also enclose parentheses in single quotes)."
Echo %str%
Pause

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "str=!str:%%=%%%%!"
Set "str=!str:(='('!"
Set "str=!str:)=')'!"
EndLocal & Set "str=%str%"

Echo %str%
Pause
```

Or similarly:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "str=Change %% to %%%%, and %%%% to %%%%%%%%, (and also enclose parentheses in single quotes)."
Echo %str% (Old variable)
Call :Validate str
Echo %str% (New variable)
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Validate
If "%~1" == "" Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_=!%~1!"
Set "_=!_:%%=%%%%!"
Set "_=!_:(='('!"
Set "_=!_:)=')'!"
EndLocal & Set "%~1=%_%"
Exit /B
```

**[EDIT /]**

And because …

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "str=Change %% to %%%%, and %%%% to %%%%%%%%, (and also enclose parentheses in single quotes)."
Echo %str% (Old variable)
Call :Validate str
Echo %str% (New variable)
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Validate
If "%~1" == "" Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_=!%~1!"
For %%G In ("%%=%%%%" "(='('" ")=')'") Do Set "_=!_:%%~G!"
EndLocal & Set "%~1=%_%"
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to retain the same code structure with the for loop and the call if that's possible.

Comment: @Ste, I have added an alternative using Call, but I'm not wasting my time with an unnecessary `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to get the for loop working as that's the title of the question as it's a neat way of replacing multiple string. I'll see if I can get it done.

Comment: I understand that you want one @Ste, but, as I said, it is unnecessary, _(and your question was technically about '`%` to be replaced with `%%`')_! Your for loop is effectively performing three commands, I've just used the same three commands! Why do you think you need one? I've done you the courtesy of adding it as an [EDIT /] regardless.

Comment: Ah, just because it's a neat solution. Thanks. I'll try to wrap my head around how that worked and mine didn't. I think it's due to `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then expanding the variable `%~1`. Great answer.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate your acceptance of the solution and feedback @Ste, just be aware that if you're wanting to use the idea as a robust solution in anything other than a test environment, you should really expand the code to first determine that any instances of `(`, or `)`, are not already preceded and/or succeeded by single quotes, _(so that you don't end up doubling those)_. I'll leave that decision and coding to you however.