# batch-file for converting file names into lowercase

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch-file to convert all files in a folder and its subfolders to lowercase. For example:

```
Here Is StackOverflow.txt
```

to

```
here is stackoverflow.txt
```

A piece of the file name is in the bracket. Is it possible to neglect it and leave it on its previous state? e.g.

```
Here Is [A WEBSITE CALLED] StackOverflow.txt
```

to

```
here is [A WEBSITE CALLED] stackoverflow.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily done with [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that renames files via regular expression replacement. JREN.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

To simply convert all file names to lower case:

```
jren "^" "" /l /s
```

If you want all text between square brackets to be upper case, and everything else to be lower case, then it is easily done with two commands

```
jren "^" "" /l /s
jren "[.+?]" "uc($0)" /j /s
```

If you want to preserve the original case of all text between square brackets, and convert everything else to lower case, then it takes a more complicated regular expression and replacement string.

```
jren "([^[]*)(\[.*?\])*" "lc($1?$1:'')+($2?$2:'')" /j /s
```

Since JREN is a batch script, you must use `CALL JREN` if you want to use the command within another batch script.

Use `jren /?` to get help on all available options.

Comment: How should I work with codes on that link? I copied batch portion of that code (from "@echo off" to "exit /b") and saved it as jren.bat and in the same folder I wrote in command line: jren /? and nothing happened.

Comment: @livingbeing - The entire code goes in JREN.BAT: both batch and JScript code. Hence the term "hybrid JScript/batch". Although if you copied just the batch portion properly into an ANSI encoded file name jren.bat, then `jren /?` should print out the help. But otherwise, the script will be useless unless it contains both the batch code and the JScript code.

Comment: @dbenham It took me few minutes to get it work but it did well the job for mass renaming of all my tv shows, from **Serie - [#x##] - Episode title** to **Serie [S##.E##] Episode title** with `jren.bat "(.*) - \[(\d)x([\d-]*)\] - (.*)" "$1+' [S0'+$2+'.E'+$3+'] '+$4" /j /s` . Great work ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Start the recursive process over the tree
call :processThisDir
goto :EOF


:processThisDir

rem Process all filenames in this folder and separate they in three parts
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=[]" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
   set "left=%%a" & set "right=%%c"

   rem Convert left and right parts to lower case
   for %%l in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      set "left=!left:%%l=%%l!"
      set "right=!right:%%l=%%l!"
   )

   rem Rename this file
   ren "%%a[%%b]%%c" "!left![%%b]!right!"
)

rem Recursively process the folders in this folder
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   cd "%%a"
   call :processThisDir
   cd ..
)

exit /B
```

Comment: Didn't work. dbenham's code did the work. +1 for considering this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another option to the answers, this will rename all the files in a folder and its subfolders to lowercase version of the name.

from cmdline:
note, make sure to `CD` to the correct dir, before running it:

```
@for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b/l/a-d') do ren "%~fi" "%~i"
```

or Batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/l/a-d') do echo ren "%%~fi" "%%~i"
```

---