# How can I change the windows USERNAME environment variable string?

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

I am looking for a solution for this after struggling for most of the day.  In short my dilemma seems simple.  An effective solution appears elusive based on the Google and Stackoverflow *hits* I've had on this one.

> (*EDIT*) 
>  I need to clarify the use-case.  We may have 6 users needing to run certain scripts that use the "`%USERNAME%`" string to login to case-sensitive environments, Linux, MySQL, etc.  One user-name is *mixed-case*.  In the example I used my name: "Will" for the scripts it must-be: "will" (all lower-case).
>
> - The general question though is how can the %USERNAME% environment variable value be change when it is *mis-entered*?

At present my Windows 7 Professional username is "will" but the environment variable has this value:

```
echo.  User = %USERNAME%
  User = Will
```

I need it to come-out as:

```
  User = will
rem      * All lower-case
```

To be clear ...

> I want to change (source) value Windows sets the USERNAME environment variable when I login.

I thought it would be *easy* to find the setting or config option to change that string -- Until I tried.  I think this must happen frequently judging from questions related to getting a USERNAME to work with cygwin, etc.

The question

- [How to convert the value of %USERNAME% to lowercase within a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284776)

Bothers me too, because that's a messy script to "*fix*" something basic in a login-environment.

I did a quick survey around the office as well.  Some people have mixed case, one or two have lowercase.  It seems arbitrary depending on what was typed-in when  account was created or something.

Our admin guy looked up my account on the domain (no, not active directory) and is same as my login-screen, "will" (lowercase).

Finally I did a couple of experiments.  I changed my username in the Users control panel

```
from:  "will" to "xxwill"
```

Thinking that would surely update my USERNAME string.  I logged out. I did it again and rebooted a second time.  The result was extremely surprising (or maybe it shouldn't have been):

```
  User = Will
rem      * NO change for the "xxwill" name-change!
```

Some further grist.  I created an account "dodo" and account "Dogdo" and changed the usernames to "Dodo" and "dogdo" respectively.

```
  User = dodo
  User = Dogdo
rem      * NO change for name-changes!
```

I see that the USERNAME can't be altered that way.  I can't edit the system environment variable in the Advanced options.  It may be in the profile.  But can you edit a profile or even look *inside* it with just Administrator powers?  I don't know yet; I'm not sure that's my preferred route either since it is hacking with a bit of "output" from some original setting, *somewhere*.

I hope someone can set me straight so I don't need that script-solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the windows USERNAME environment variable string, you can do this in the **Advanced User Accounts** Control Panel.

Open it by running **netplwiz** ("C:\Windows\System32\Netplwiz.exe", **net**work **pl**aces **wiz**ard).
Then select the name you want to change and click on the Properties button.
Now you get the properties of the selected user account: you can change the User name (, Full name & Description) here.
You'll (just) need administrator rights to do this.

Log out and log on, open a command prompt and try to output the value for **%USERNAME%**. You'll notice it has been changed according to your modification.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "%temp%"
COPY NUL "%username%" >NUL 2>NUL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /L /b "%username%"') DO set "usernamelc=%%a"
del "%username%" >NUL 2>NUL
POPD
ECHO %USERNAME% --^> %usernamelc%
GOTO :EOF
```

Perhaps this may help. YMMV.

Comment: I want to NOT need to manipulate the value.  I think that Windows should set USERNAME to the name I logged in with.  Since it _won't_ I need to change it explicitly.  If it is possible.

Comment: You could directly set `username` rather than `usernamelc` if you want, but such a setting is then only valid for the current `cmd` instance. It is re-established for other instances on creation of each instance, but setting it as a user variable overrides the system-setting (in that `cmd` instance)

Comment: I think there must be a misunderstanding.  CREATE a username of "Fred" o your Windows PC.  Then change the login user's name to (say): "Malcom".  So now the username is "Malcom".  When YOU login as _Malcom_ -- and print `echo %USERNAME%` ...  The output shall be, "Fred" (forever thus).   I wannaknow, how to modify the string that is _loaded-in-to_ ... USERNAME during login.

Comment: I don't play around with user-accounts since my system is only used by me and I'm not in a corporate environment. Think about the consequences of changing your username. How would you handle files' ownership and access for instance - If you're "Superman" today and "Batman" tomorrow, how is the system supposed to track those changes for network, local, cloud or off-line devices? Compared to that nighmare, propagating directory-change-date/time from a deep directory through to root (which Windows doesn't do) would be a doddle... Login name not necessarily = account name appears true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you are saying, but it might be achievable, you will know by playing around with the locations where usernames are defined.

• Firstly, there is the user folder `C:\user\username1` and that is defined at user creation. This can (I think) be changed (I've only seen references to it, but there are many references, this is easy to find).

• Secondly, there is the `Control Panel > User Accounts > Change My Name`. This seems to tie in with your $env:USERNAME

• Finally, there is the `lusrmgr.msc > Users`. This is tied most closely to your "real" username, and aligns with `[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()`
I say "real" because I found this recently when trying to use `ssh-keygen` to create a public key and although my Display Name and $env:USERNAME were set to "Name1", `ssh-keygen` would only see "Name2" and I had to alter the name in `lusrmgr.msc` to fix this (a reboot was required).

This is an old post, but posting in case this can help anyone with similar issues.