# How to get current folder name in lowercase as variable in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get the current directory folder name in **lowercase** form.

I understand I can get the current folder name with the following:

```
for %I in (.) do echo %~nxI
```

but I have no idea on how to convert that to lowercase.

I need to use it in a single line command.

for %I in (.) do echo %~nxI

### What i am after:

```
c:\Program Files
for %I in (.) do echo %~nxI ---edited
program files
```

### Currently getting

```
c:\Program Files
for %I in (.) do echo %~nxI
Program Files
```

Comment: You can take a look at this [How to convert the value of %USERNAME% to lowercase within a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284776/how-to-convert-the-value-of-username-to-lowercase-within-a-windows-batch-scrip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using `dir /b /l`, but unlike [Gerhard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58520158/1012053), without need of a temp file.

From the command line:

```
for %A in (.) do @for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /l /ad "..\%~nxA*"^|findstr /xic:"%~nxA"') do @echo %F
```

Within a batch script:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (.) do for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /l /ad "..\%%~nxA*" ^| findstr /xic:"%%~nxA"'
) do echo %%F
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Works exactly as needed.

Comment: Yeah, this is a better option for this specific case. We need to revert to temp file however if any other strings needs to be converted and we use `dir /l`, but yeah, you win `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Using pure batch, with temp file:

Single line `cmd`:

```
@for %i in (.) do echo>"%temp%\%~nxi" & @dir /b /l "%temp%\%~nxi" & @del /Q "%temp%\%~nxi"
```

or in a `batch-file`

```
@echo off
for %%i in (.) do set "var=%%~nxi"
echo>"%temp%\%var%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /l "%temp%\%var%"') do echo %%a & del /Q "%temp%\%var%"
```

or slightly shorter, without echo:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (.) do (
  echo>"%temp%\%%~nxi"
  dir /b /l "%temp%\%%~nxi"
  del /Q "%temp%\%%~nxi"
)
```

Comment: works great, but a little worried about creating and then deleting files. But as it creates the file in the temp directory. Risk is minimal.

Comment: yeah, well quick answer I made without having time to do more, but @dbenham already made the needed changes in his answer.

Comment: similar, but will only work for files and directories.. to use `dir /l` for other strings you still require temp files.  `@for %i in (.) do for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b/l ..\^|findstr /xic:"%~nxi"') do @echo %a`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows platform, it will have PowerShell.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Split-Path -Leaf -Path (Get-Location)).ToLower()"
```

If you want the result in a variable in a .bat file script:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Split-Path -Leaf -Path (Get-Location)).ToLower()"') DO (SET "LCCD=%%~A")
ECHO %LCCD%
```

Of course, if you could use PowerShell without cmd.exe, it would just be:

```
(Split-Path -Leaf -Path (Get-Location)).ToLower()
```

Comment: Seems to give me the entire path, rather then just the current folder name

Comment: Revised to produce only the current directory name and not a fully qualified path.